# Pull to Refresh WebView swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode

I have gone through many tutorials and have still not been able to implement pull to refresh for my webview.  All of the tutorials I have found either are not updated to swift or not for a webview.

Sorry I am new to swift.

Here is the most promising method I tried, it compiled with no errors but there is not pull to refresh

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: 
UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var cnerror: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var cnretry: UIButton!
@IBAction func cnretry(_ sender: Any) {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        webview.isHidden = false
        cnerror.isHidden = true
        cnretry.isHidden = true
        webview.reload()
    }else{
        webview.isHidden = true
        cnerror.isHidden = false
        cnretry.isHidden = false
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "redir", withExtension: "html")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let day_url = URL(string: "https://branch.zylas.net/")
    let day_url_request = URLRequest(url: day_url!,
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
                                     timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    let day_webView = UIWebView()
    webview.scrollView.delegate = self;
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0){
            //reach top
            print("Reach Top")
            webview.reload()
        }
    }
    day_webView.loadRequest(day_url_request)
    webview.load(request)
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        webview.isHidden = false
    }else{
        webview.isHidden = true
        cnerror.isHidden = false
        cnretry.isHidden = false
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}

}
```

Comment: Your code contains absolutely no reference to a pull to refresh controller.  Can you at least show what you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I added the failed code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

var refController:UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true



    let url = URL.init(string: "https://www.google.com")
    let requestObj = URLRequest.init(url: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17"])




    refController.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 50.0, width: refController.bounds.size.width, height: refController.bounds.size.height)
    refController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.mymethodforref(refresh:)), for: .valueChanged)
    refController.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    webView.scrollView.addSubview(refController)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


@objc func mymethodforref(refresh:UIRefreshControl){
    webView.reload()
    refController.endRefreshing()
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}
```

try this code I have implemented UIrefreshController to achieve pull to refresh